# Screw post or binding post on PCB for lugged gnd wire?

Tags: pcb, connector

I need to attach these four wires to a PCB I am designing.

The three ferruled wires will be connected through a terminal block. I have space next to the terminal block for the lug but I need a method for connecting the lug to the PCB.

A simple solution is just a plated through hole, connected to ground. I could then bolt the lug directly to the PCB.

I would prefer a binding post of some kind I could solder directly to the PCB and then attach the lug to the binding post.

Does anyone know where I can find a connector like this? I'm coming up empty searching the usual places. I don't know what the correct name for this part would be.

[image: ferrules with lug]

Comment: You can't even get binding posts that solder to a PCB can you? Use a screw terminal: https://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/keyelco/Screw-Terminals-Terminal-Blocks/id/476

Comment: @DKNguyen i dont know, why i was asking!

Comment: You can't. But you don't need one. See above.

Comment: @DKNguyen oh the screw terminal is the way to go, thanks!

Comment: The word "lug" usually refers to a much heavier-duty connector than this; this is just a ring terminal.

Comment: @Hearth i know, i usually work on much higher voltage, current, guage, etc.

Comment: @bradburydoom Right, but looking at the title I was expecting you'd have some requirements for very high current, when actually you can probably use some pretty standard screw terminals to connect this to the PCB. Should you need to do this for high current in the future, though, I suggest Würth Elektronik's REDCUBE series of screw terminals.

Comment: @Hearth Post that as an answer since these products are proprietary and go by different names from each company.

Comment: It seems that the question assumes uncommon meanings for both of the terms "lug" and "binding post". A [lug](https://westech-pv.com/media/image/product/1059/lg/crimping-cable-lug-m8-x-10mm.jpg) is usually a bit larger than a ring terminal, and a [binding post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:BindingPostRed.jpg) does not fit either of them.

Comment: I'd certainly look into whether a stand-off could be abused / would be cheaper than anything else mentioned here.

Comment: How many accidentel force do you expect the pcb's ground lug to be subjected to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PCB solderable binding posts don't exist.

All-metal PCB solderable screw terminal things do though but unfortunately the names they go by (such as screw terminals) overlaps with terminal blocks so you have to search. Usually a random visual search of images in Mouser or Digikey. These things:

[image]
https://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/keyelco/Screw-Terminals-Terminal-Blocks/id/476

Comment: Digikey has [a product category](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/terminals/screw-connectors/396) specifically for these. Mouser might as well; I don't use Mouser as often.

Comment: @Hearth perfect, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Hearth I just remember seeing images of them on Digikey or Mouser search results while searching for other items long before I needed them and it took me a long time to find them again when I did need them. "Screw terminals" in the search was insufficient if I recall since that would be the first thing I would try. But I try that on Digikey now and it comes up fairly quick. Maybe it was Mouser. I usually use Mouser.

Answer (score 10):

We use broaching fasteners for PCBs:

[image]

They are installed on the PCB with an arbor press.

Made by PEM manufacturing.

https://catalog.pemnet.com/category/nuts-broaching-types-kf2-kfs2

You can get them from https://www.dbroberts.com/

Comment: Note that PCB material can creep under pressure, loosening the connection when the board itself is being clamped; it's a good idea to use spring washers (conical / Belleville) to provide some compliance.

Comment: @Tim Williams I don't know if you can see it in the third picture, but there is a split washer under the screw head. Not a Belleville, though.

Comment: Ah, good catch -- though I would caution against split washers, as they provide very little spring force (nor locking force once clamped flat).

Comment: Can you get away with a nylon mallet rather than a press?

Comment: @DKNguyen I wouldn't use a mallet, you'd probably get some successes but also some mangled boards. It's important that the nut goes in straight or it makes a mess, and it's challenging to hit it perfectly square by hand.  A decent quality vice or toolmakers clamp works pretty well (but not as reliable and consistent as a press). I have also used a drill press, switched off and with a piece of silver steel in place of the drill bit, that works well.

Answer (score 8):

Consider also threaded-rod press-fit terminals:

https://www.digikey.com/short/bb834t43

[image: Würth Elektronik 7460719]

{Source: [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/w%C3%BCrth-elektronik/7460719/2682510)}

Answer (score 2):

There are also SMT variations: https://www.we-online.com/en/components/products/WP-SMBU_THROUGH-HOLE

Answer (score 1):

If you have exposed ground like pictured in [Davide's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/697080/568) it is possible to do the same he suggest but with simpler hardware you can get in any hardware shop, just use a short M3 or M4 bolt, corresponding nut and a lock washer.

[image: lock washer]

Comment: Beware, star washers severely mar the PCB surface, making them one- or few-time fasteners at best; preferably, thick copper (2oz+) should be used on the board for this reason.  Note PCB material can flow under pressure (creep), so a spring washer e.g. conical type is desirable (maybe in addition to the star washer, if that's not too awkward for reason of combining washers).

Comment: I'm fond of using bronze lock washers for this, which are slightly more specialty but can be ordered from McMaster. I don't have any hard data for this but I think they are a little less harsh on the PCB than steel ones. They have better electrical conductivity too, but I doubt that's very significant.

Comment: @Hearth Go with brass. Softer, cheaper, better conductivity, and more available than bronze.

Answer (score 1):

The fasteners in the answer by Davide are made by PEM.  They also make solderable studs.  You press them into a plated-thru hole, maybe thread on a spacer to lift the ring terminal above the board, and fasten the terminal with either a standard nut, a KEPS nut, or a wing nut.

https://catalog.pemnet.com/category/studs-broaching-type-kfh

https://catalog.pemnet.com/viewitems/studs-broaching-type-kfh/broaching-studs-type-kfh-unified#